# GTK4 C: Changing Button Sensitivity Programmatically, But UI Not Updating

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk4

I am working on a GTK application in C, and I am facing an issue where I change the sensitivity of buttons programmatically in response to a button click. Although the sensitivity values seem to change correctly when I print them for debugging, the UI does not reflect these changes visually.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
 // Enable the sensitivity of the buttons
    GtkWidget *button_add = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(main_builder, "button_add"));
    GtkWidget *button_delete = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(main_builder, "button_delete"));
    GtkWidget *button_show_content = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(main_builder, "button_show_content"));
    GtkWidget *button_modify_content = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(main_builder, "button_modify_content"));

    // Testing ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    gboolean add_is_sensitive_before = gtk_widget_get_sensitive(button_add);
    gboolean delete_is_sensitive_before = gtk_widget_get_sensitive(button_delete);
    gboolean show_is_sensitive_before = gtk_widget_get_sensitive(button_show_content);
    gboolean modify_is_sensitive_before = gtk_widget_get_sensitive(button_modify_content);
    printf("Add Sensitivity: %s\n", add_is_sensitive_before ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    printf("Add Sensitivity: %s\n", delete_is_sensitive_before ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    printf("Add Sensitivity: %s\n", show_is_sensitive_before ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    printf("Add Sensitivity: %s\n", modify_is_sensitive_before ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");

    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(button_add, false);
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(button_delete, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(button_show_content, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(button_modify_content, TRUE);

    gboolean add_is_sensitive_after = gtk_widget_get_sensitive(button_add);
    gboolean delete_is_sensitive_after = gtk_widget_get_sensitive(button_delete);
    gboolean show_is_sensitive_after = gtk_widget_get_sensitive(button_show_content);
    gboolean modify_is_sensitive_after = gtk_widget_get_sensitive(button_modify_content);
    printf("Add Sensitivity: %s\n", add_is_sensitive_after ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    printf("Add Sensitivity: %s\n", delete_is_sensitive_after ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    printf("Add Sensitivity: %s\n", show_is_sensitive_after ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    printf("Add Sensitivity: %s\n", modify_is_sensitive_after ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
```

and this was the output:

```
Add Sensitivity: TRUE
Add Sensitivity: FALSE
Add Sensitivity: FALSE
Add Sensitivity: FALSE

Add Sensitivity: FALSE
Add Sensitivity: TRUE
Add Sensitivity: TRUE
Add Sensitivity: TRUE
```

The issue is that even though the sensitivity values are updated, the UI does not visually change to reflect these updates. I've confirmed that the signal handlers are connected correctly, and other UI changes in the same functions are reflected as expected.